# Charging a 2020 M1 Macbook Pro from a low-voltage solar array

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, circuits, photovoltaics

I'm working on a small project to mount solar panels to a Macbook case which would allow it to charge/offset battery consumption.

I noticed that I was able to power the Macbook on public transport using a standard 5V 1A USB-A socket that Auckland Transport provided, under the Mac's system information it showed it was drawing 5W and the battery was slowly discharging.

I have a bunch of very small solar cells, each rated for 0.5V, 0.32A, 0.16W. Though I haven't tested this. I think I could fit 14 solar cells wired in series, and duplicate this three times in parallel for a 7V, 0.96A, 6.72W cell.

The laptop seems to charge perfectly fine off a 5V, 1A supply and obviously works fine off a 20V wall charger.  My question is will it work okay with a 7V output (especially if the output is variable)? Should I wire it up differently to target a higher/lower voltage?

Comment: The voltage coming directly from solar cells is low and variable with the light. Normally there is a DC/DC converter that produces the nominal output voltage of the system. In principle this voltage can be anything, so might as well pick parts that give 5V or 20V to make it easy for your laptop. What level of integration are your components? Is the main question here about whether or not the laptop accepts 7V?

Comment: 10% overvoltage should be tolerated, 40% not so much. It's not necessarily that it can't work with 7 V, but if it is expecting 5 V because the appropriate handshake hasn't been performed, it could break it. I am not an electronics engineer.